# Set column value in first row of sorted MultiIndex DataFrame with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 'A', 5.0, 0.0),
                        (2, 'A', 3.0, 0.0),
                        (1, 'B', 1.0, 0.0),
                        (2, 'B', 2.0, 0.0),
                        (1, 'C', 6.0, 2.0)],
                  columns=('Date', 'Name', 'limit', 'allocation')).set_index(['Date','Name'])
groups = df.groupby('Date')
group = groups.get_group(1)
groupSorted = group.sort_values(by='limit', ascending=False)
```

Now `groupSorted` looks like this:

```
           limit  allocation
Date Name                   
1    C       6.0         2.0
     A       5.0         0.0
     B       1.0         0.0
```

Having produced the `groupSorted` sub-DataFrame, **I want a formula to `set` the `allocation` on the first row satisfying the condition that `allocation` is 0**.  How can I do that?

I've found various ways to *select* the first row with that condition.  E.g.,

```
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0].iloc[0]
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0].head(1)
```

... and even ways to *get* the *value* I want to change:

```
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0].iat[0, 1]
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0].iloc[0].at['allocation']
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0].iloc[0]['allocation']
groupSorted[groupSorted.allocation == 0]['allocation'].iat[0]
```

But none of them allow me to *set* that value.  **How can I set that value so that it "sticks" in the original `group` and `df`?**

Comment: Are you sure when you are making changes you are modifying inplace and not making a new df?

Comment: @noah: If I make changes to `group` it applies to the parent `df`.  By the time I'm modifying `groupSorted` I'm not sure....  So setting the value on the *sorted, conditioned* group is part of the problem.

Comment: I think you want `groupSorted.loc[groupSorted['allocation'] == 0, 'allocation'].values[0] = 12345`

Comment: @cs95: I tried that, but it doesn't alter the value of anything in `groupSorted`.  If I do `groupSorted.loc[groupSorted['allocation'] == 0, 'allocation'].iloc[0] = 123` I at least get the `SettingWithCopyWarning`....

Comment: It works for me. You can also try `groupSorted.loc[(groupSorted['allocation'] == 0).idxmax(), 'allocation'] = 12345` And if that doesn't work, the problem's likely not with code.

Comment: That second variant – using `.idxmax()` – does work!  But it doesn't affect the pre-sorted `group` or `df`.  Is there a way to get that row changed in the original dataframe?

Comment: Pandas has been designed to avoid "side effects" like that. The settingWithCopyWarning is a good example of that. If you want to modify the original group then you will have to call `df.update(groupSorted)` to persist it. That's the best advice I can give.

Comment: @cs95 that should work, but I'd appreciate any answer that gives a pandalicious way of accomplishing this that will scale efficiently with the number of rows and groups.  (I want to apply this logic recursively across the groups in the root dataframe.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments to the question:

To assign to the `groupSorted` we can use:

```
groupSorted.loc[(groupSorted['allocation'] == 0).idxmax(), 'allocation'] = 123
```

To get the assignment to "stick" in the original DataFrame we can do:

```
df.at[(groupSorted['allocation'] == 0).idxmax()] = 123
```